# SQLite dynamic query

Tags: android, sqlite, dynamic, where-clause

I have a SQLite database, and what i want to do is that an user selects a filter. For example i have a database of books, and a user just want to look data from "Agata christies books"..

So i made a spinner with the options to select, and then with an intent i pass the field selected to another activity which executes the query select.

My question is, how can i make the dynamic query?  Think that i have more than 1 filter, how can i make the clause WHERE depending on the data i passed from the other activity by an intent?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy way but tried and true:

```
String query = "Select id FROM books WHERE 1=1"
if (condition1) query+= " AND name="+theName;
if (condition2) query+= " AND author="+theAuthor;
if (condition3) query+= " AND price="+thePrice;
```

If you have full control of options aka via spinners, this is safe.  If its an edittext, use preparedStatements and bind the arguments to avoid SQLI.

Comment: i think condition where 1 = 1 so everytime is true, doesn't works. 

cause im just doing this : ` String query = "Select * FROM Incidentes WHERE 1=1"
Cursor d = db2.rawQuery(query,null);`    and this doesn't give me all the table

Answer (score 0):

[public Cursor rawQuery (String sql, String[] selectionArgs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Generate String SQL with `?` for binding and add arguments in selectionArgs.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean filterName = false;
boolean filterPrice = false;
ArrayList<String> selectionArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
String query = "SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE 1=1";
if(filterName) {
    selectionArgs.add(searchString);
    query += " AND NAME = ?";
}
if(filterPrice) {
    selectionArgs.add(priceString);
    query += " AND PRICE= ?";
}

Cursor c = m_Database.rawQuery(query, (String[])selectionArgs1.toArray());
```

Comment: but i need some WHERE. if i put data in the filters in the spinner, i have to put another WHERE.   I want agatha christies, and prize 10 dolars.

so `String[] selectionArgs = {prizeSelected,authorSelected + "%"};
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE NAME = ?", selectionArgs);`

if i have 2 conditions how can i call some wheres clause? i dont even know why u use "%"

Comment: Hi, sorry. I updated my answer for two arguments. You can add more if you need.

Comment: thanks, but think that maybe i sometimes need a filter, and some times not.
So maybe i want to filter by price and not by author, so my author filter is not filled.

How can i manage this? because where price = ? its ok, but author = ? i dont need it in some querys .  thanks

Comment: Actually just realized that it is very similar to what @yep suggested

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the smartiest way to do it, but assume you know in advance you can have 1 integer filters (price) and 1 string filter (author name), I'd try :

SELECT * FROM BOOKS
WHERE
       (price<0 OR AND BOOKS.price = price ) AND
       (author="" OR BOOKS.author = author);

I'm not an SQLite expert, please check syntax. The trick is here to set price < 0 if the filter is not set (hence all lines are taken into account since condition price<0 is true), and set author as an empty string to not to filter on the author (SELECT will not filter out these lines since condition is true).

This will work !

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm using student data as an example

```
public ArrayList<Student>getStudent(int stdID,String stdName)
{
ArrayList<Student> studentArr = new ArrayList<>();
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = null;

String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblstudent WHERE 1=1";
String sqlParam = "";

/*Here we're building the dynamic sql.*/

if(stdID > 0)
{
sqlQuery += " AND std_id = ?";
sqlParam = String.valueOf(stdID);
}

if(!stdName.trim().isEmpty())
{
sqlQuery += " AND std_name = ?";
sqlParam = stdName.trim();
}

/*Do this to avoid SQL injection Attack (SIA) [it's very important!]*/
sqlParam = sqlParam.replaceAll(";|--","");


 if (db != null) {
    
  if (!sqlParam.isEmpty()) {

    cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL,new String[]{sqlParam});
        
    }else {
   /*if  the "sqlParam" is empty.*/

   cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL,null);
    }
 if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0) {

 while(cursor.moveToNext()){

Student stdmodel = new Student();

stdmodel.setstdID(cursor.getInt(0));
stdmodel.stdName(cursor.getString(1));

studentArr.add(stdmodel);
}

 cursor.close();
  }
}

return studentArr;
}
```

Comment: If no argument is passed in any of the parameters, the "WHERE 1=1" clause returns all the data.