# Is there a simpler way to transfer data between an android application and a server database?

Tags: c#, android, sql, sql-server, json

At the moment, in my app, I currently have an SQLite database, for where I store relevant information that needs to be eventually sent to the database or for later recalling in the app (or both). This is done the traditional way using the SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// define constants to store names of each table and each field name

// Tables

public static final String TABLE_VISIT_DETAILS = "VisitDetails";
...
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Projects.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 41;

// Database table creation sql statements, SQLite requires tables to be
// created in separate statements

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_VISIT_DETAILS = "create table "
        + TABLE_VISIT_DETAILS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_PROJECT_NUMBER
        + " text not null, " + COLUMN_SITE_VISIT_ID + " integer, "
        + COLUMN_SCHEDULED_START_TIME + " integer, "
        + COLUMN_SCHEDULED_END_TIME + " integer, " + COLUMN_POSTCODE
        + " text, " + COLUMN_SUBMITTED + " text, " + COLUMN_SITE_NAME
        + " text, " + COLUMN_SITE_ADDRESS + " text, " + COLUMN_PROJECT_TYPE
        + " text, " + COLUMN_CLIENT + " text, "
        + COLUMN_REINSPECTION_PROJECT + " text, " + COLUMN_VISIT_NUMBER
        + " integer);";
...
etc
```

And I just store objects quite simply. Before, I had used JSONObject and JSONArray to send JSON requests to the server, but now I've changed that to Gson for a lot easier use of serialisation and make the need to use the put method for each attribute into the json objects.

I have an API set up on my server which waits on these json objects which it then parses, eg:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadSurveyData/{token}", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<UploadProjectContainerResult> UploadSurveyData(string token, UploadProjectContainer data)
    {
        List<UploadProjectContainerResult> results = new List<UploadProjectContainerResult>();
        MobileAssessorAuthenticationResults authResult = ValidateToken(new Guid(token));

        SqlCommand command = null;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        if (authResult == MobileAssessorAuthenticationResults.Success)
        {
            results.Add(uploadQuestionnaireResponse(token, data.questionnaireResponses));
            results.Add(uploadBuildings(token, data.buildings));
            results.Add(uploadFloors(token,data.floors ));
            results.Add(uploadLocations(token, data.locations));

            String projectDir = "";
            command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetProjectDir]", _connector.Connection);
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectNo", data.siteInfo.projectNo);

            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                projectDir = reader.GetString(0);
            }

            results.Add(uploadSiteInfo(token, data.siteInfo, projectDir));                        
            results.Add(uploadSubmission(token,data.submission, projectDir, data.scheduleId));
        }

        return results;
    }
```

It makes an object of the container and then goes through each thing in the container and runs a stored procedure in a SQL database to add them to the database and returns a result for each one (whether it's successful or not). It then returns an array of those results back, and tells the app each of them indicating to the user if they were successful or not.

It's quite annoying adding new stuff, or even changing stuff using this system as it has to be changed in several places.

I was wondering if there was something I could implement to make this a lot simpler and quicker to do or if any it were redundant and could be be replaced by something else.

On the whole, I'd just like to cut down the whole process a lot for this and future projects. I don't mind starting from scratch again, if only to increase productivity later on.

I'm using C# with .NET framework as my webservice API, SQL Server 10.50.1600 as my SQL database, android with 2.3.3 as my minimum platform for the devices, so these are my limitations and are the things that aren't flexible to change. Any external libraries are welcome, of course, if they are compatible.

If you'd like me to include more of my code, feel free to ask. It will become commercial code for the company I work for, so I cannot disclose the entire source, but I am willing to show as much as is needed (if that makes sense).

Thank you very much for reading and helping me!

**EDIT: ** Bump.

Answer (score 0):

[Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet) transfers object graphs and comes with its own serialization library.  It's pretty simple and quick to implement as far as client / server networking. Concerning the refactoring of your code, you're probably in the best position to pull out the redundant pieces.

Comment: It's more so the DB stuff, where I have the problem with redundancy. I have to add it in about 6 or 7 places, just to add a new attribute or change one. I have it add it to the DB, to the service object, to the stored procedure, to the android db and android objects. I don't see how it'd simplify it since I've sorted out the serialisation issue with the Gson library.

Comment: Oooohh that makes a little more sense.  Well, if you come across a library that does all that for you it will be the end of development teams lol.

Comment: alternatively, you could add http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml 
to remove some of the updating required

Comment: I'd love to come across it =P. Essentially, I'd want to implement it rather than find a library for it. Implement it in a similar manner, so I'd simply have a list of all the objects, and their attributes, and if I added one, gave it its type for each respective place (text in sqlite, nvarchar in sql, String for C# and Java), then it can delivery instructions to add them. Although this means making the design of the DBs and object formation dynamic. Is that possible?

Comment: In other words, if I wanted to add, say Houses as an object. I'd have "Houses: {NoOfRooms : {SQLite : integer, SQL : int, Android: integer, C# : integer}, HouseName : {SQLite : text, SQL: nvarchar(50), Android: String, C# : String}}", etc. Something like that, which would then add it dynamically to each part.

Comment: @Gentatsu You could do it just as dynamic arrays are "dynamic".  Recreate the entity (with the changes made) and then import the data from the old DB entity.  Similar with objects, recreate the object and then rewire the frame to the new object

Comment: @Gentatsu you could definitely do that. You'd just have to write your own parser and dynamic scripts

Comment: @Gentatsu [see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647999/sqlite-dynamic-query) for dynamic sqlite querying

Comment: How do I create dynamic sqlite tables(as in new tables on whim), microsoft sql tables and objects, though? I wouldn't want them to be held in the array. And how would I even retrieve them from these dynamic databases? Say I decided I want to display the house information, but I've got no physical code of the house in the code, it's just in that dictionary, as mentioned above. I'd assume to know the attributes I'd be using, though. Or would I do it like I'd parse a JSON file, getting each attribute to return a dictionary of more stuff? Main thing's the database stuff, though.

Comment: I don't particularly mind having to create my own objects in the code, since I can use it more freely. It's just the management of the DBs along with the code which is annoying.

Comment: @Gentatsu that's exactly what I'd do (JSON file).  See [scaffolding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_(programming))

Comment: @Gentatsu maybe you should consider something like Parse (parse.com) and drop your backend? (depends on the project though)

Comment: @DamianWalczak I did a bunch of serialisation to reduce it a lot. On the server side, it's all the same. Put the fields in the db, create the class, and stored procedure to get them. On the client side, I've reduced it a lot. I've gotten rid of receiving/putting things in to the SQLite DB by serialising the json in to contentvalues whereby the column names matches the object variables and the json fields. Then I deserialise the cursor in to objects. It wasn't terribly hard to make these de/serialisers. It also encourages less errors in naming, since it'll throw an error if they're ill-named.